# Div won't resize vertically in slideshow with CSS queries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm working on [this page](http://parpeds.com/test-homepage/) and trying to get the slideshow to display correctly at tablet and mobile widths with media queries. However, all of the slider container elements are setting their height to 590px and this is creating a large gap beneath the slider and its content. I don't belive any of the elements have a fixed height set, but I have used some `max-height:590px` here and there. Any thoughts on how to get rid of that gap and force the containers to resize correctly?

Slider uses Cycle2.

Some HTML code

```
<div id="slider" class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-pager="#adv-custom-pager" data-cycle-slides="> div" data-cycle-timeout="7000">

<div class="singleSlide">
  <!-- content goes in here -->
</div>
```

And some CSS that I think is important:

```
#homeslider {
    height: auto;
}
#homeslider, #slider img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
#homeslider {
    width: 1090px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    max-height: 590px;
}
```

For reference, [this slideshow](http://parpeds.com/) is the expected behavior.

ETA: Added some of the code that I *think* is important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.slidercaption` you have a `top:-200px` which is causing the issue. Unlike `margin`, elements with `position:relative` won't physically move when you set a `top` or `left` style. That means the occupied space for that element will still remain on that position.

So to fix that, remove `top: -200px` and replace with `margin-top: -200px` instead.

**From this:**

```
.slidercaption {
  position: relative;
  top: -200px;
}
```

**To this:**

```
.slidercaption {
  margin-top: -200px
}
```

Take note, in your css there's a `margin:0` set in that element. Make sure your update will override that existing style.

**Update:**

A far better solution is to use `position:absolute` instead, since having a negative margin or position is more likely to get an issue with that huge value.

So...

**From:**

```
.slidercaption {
  position: relative;
  top: -200px;
}
```

**To:**

```
.slidercaption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Then what was causing the below elements to go up is because of this:

```
#sliderNav {
  margin-top: -190px;
}
```

**Change that to:**

```
#sliderNav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 168px;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

When you came to a point where you are using large negative values, you can use [`position:absolute`](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) instead which is very helpful and less likely to have some issues if used properly.

Comment: This fixes the problem (thank you!) but creates a new one - the callout boxes beneath the slider are jumping onto the top of new content because the containers are collapsing too much now (opposite problem as before!) Any thoughts? - http://parpeds.com/test-homepage/

Comment: Thank you so much - now I just have to finish off the position of the dots for tablet and mobile views!

Comment: @Stevie Cool! Great to hear. Happy coding :)

Comment: I'm having another problem with the positioning again (this is the bane of my existence, seriously). Between 768 and 550px width, the slider navigation dots in `#sliderNav` will not stay properly positioned above the headline in the yellow box. Other widths work. Any ideas? http://parpeds.com/test-homepage/

Comment: @Stevie I noticed the issue is because of `max-height: 590px;` on `#slider` element. When you remove that, the dots will now stay properly when you resize. Also I noticed on `.slidercaption` you got a fixed height and min height of `250px`. I think it would be better if you make the height `auto` then set padding instead to create spacing. - but of course maybe you got some reason for doing that, then you can ignore my suggestion.